# Adding Custom Brackets labels for Statistical comparisons manually in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, brackets, stat, ggpubr

I have data (data.se) that I want to use to add custom bracket comparison after running a multivariate linear model with adjustment. I need to modify the stat labels and want to show the comparisons related to the model in my plot, not something that is directly calculated because our research warranted adjustments to the statistic tests that may otherwise be used with stat_compare_means(). However, I could not figure how to customize the brackets.

I found a solution that appears to work with ggpubr's geom_bracket(), but when I try to add multiple comparisons, it breaks.

Any suggestions? I merely want to code brackets into my plot for custom labeling.

[a summary of the data to give me the mean, and 95% confidence interval for the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i32hl.png)

data.se is my data and its structure can be seen in the image.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)
library(Rmisc)
library(ggplot2)

    data.se = scaled.data
    data.se = summarySE(data.se, groupvars = c("visit", "shunt_decision"), measurevar = "abs_change")

VisitColors <-c("PreLD"="#E69F00",
                "PostLD" = "#56B4E9",
                "FU6Month" =  "#009E73",
                "FU12Month" = "#D55E00")

    data.figure.2AaPoint <- ggplot(data= data.se[data.se$shunt_decision %like% "Yes", ], mapping =  aes(y =(abs_change*100), x= visit,color=visit, group = visit))+
  geom_point(aes(size = 1.5), show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), size=1.5)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=(abs_change*100)+(ci*100),
                    ymin=(abs_change*100)-(ci*100)),
                width = .2,
                size=2)+
  ggtitle(NULL, "Shunt Decision: Yes")+
  labs(x='Visit',
       y="Gait Stride Length Change from Pre LDT (cm)",
       fill= "Shunt Decision",
       tag = "A")+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_hline(yintercept =0)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-50,50, 10), 
                     limits = c(-50,50))+
  scale_x_discrete(labels= c("Pre LDT", "Post LDT","6 Months", "12 Months"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = VisitColors,
                     name= paste("Visit (trials)"), labels= c(
                       "PreLD"= paste("Pre LDT", "(",n.pre.y, ")"),
                       "PostLD"= paste("Post LDT", "(",n.post.y,")"),
                       #"FU6Week"= paste("FU6Week"),
                       "FU6Month"= paste("6 Months", "(",n.FU6M.y,")"),
                       "FU12Month"= paste("12 Months", "(",n.FU12M.y,")"),
                       "Control"= paste("Control: ","(",n.control,")",sep = "")
                     ))+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color=NA),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        #axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.8, hjust=.8),
        #axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(size=11),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, face= "italic"),
        #legend.position = c(.55,.85),
        legend.position = c(.175,.17),
        plot.tag.position = c(0.2, 0.875),
        plot.tag = element_text(face= "bold", size = 20),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.key.size = unit(.375, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.height = unit(.375, 'cm'), 
        legend.key.width = unit(.375, 'cm'))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2))+
  geom_bracket(data= data.se[data.se$shunt_decision %like% "Yes", ],
               mapping=aes(x=visit, y=abs_change*100),
               xmin = c("PreLD", "PostLD"),
               xmax =  c("PostLD", "FU6Month"),
               label = c("test1", "test2"),
              type = "text",
               y.position = c(30,35),
               #tip.length = -.1,
              vjust = 2.25)
#facet_wrap(~shunt_decision, strip.position = "bottom")

print(data.figure.2AaPoint)
```

Comment: Could you make your example both **minimal** and **reproducible**? We can't test modifications of your code on a picture of your data--sharing data with`dput()` is standard as it is copy/pasteable an includes all class and structure information, e.g., `dput(data.se[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Pick a suitable subset to illustrate the problem.

Comment: It would also help focus your question if you can delete any code that's not really relevant. For example, if the 15 lines of `theme()` settings don't impact the issue, removing them from the question helps keep it concise and focused on the actual problem.

Comment: this should explain how to make your code reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/a/73250754/5224236